# Determining MIDI note length

Tags: c++, midi

I'm trying to understand the way .midi files are played on the computer.
I do understand concept of note on/ note off messages and it's parameter's, but I just don't get how note length is set.
Making sound with bare hands is pretty easy (note on/ delay / note off), but is there such thing as delay in MIDI byte code? 
Running a .midi tune gives accurate note lengths and pauses between notes, how is that done? Is there a message for a delay?

Comment: Review the top two entries in [this table](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The syntax of an MTrk event is very simple:
>
> `<MTrk event> = <delta-time><event>`
>
> `<delta-time>` is stored as a variable-length quantity. It represents the amount of time before the following event.

Source: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/readings/Standard-MIDI-file-format-updated.pdf